# iOS 11 Nivagation bar sharp animation

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

When I set the navigation bar property:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic
```

I observe sharp animation on scroll. I want animation exactly same as if this option is true. See pictures below.

Smooth (with isTranslucent = true)
[image: smooth]

Sharp (with isTranslucent = false)
[image: sharp]